# How to match the first element of two different list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists like this:

```
list1[(0,123),(1,456)]
list2[(0,'asd'),(2,'dsa'),(0,'eqw')]
```

I want merge above two lists into one where the first element in both lists is matched, for example, `0` in `list1` can be found in `list2`, the output should like

```
list3[(0,123,'asd','eqw')]
```

I tried this code, but seems not work:

```
out = [i for i,j in zip(list1, list2) if list1[0][0] == list[0][0]]
```

Can someone give me any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a good reason to not use a dictionary?

Comment: @Nils_M because in list2 there are many duplicates elements

Comment: duplicates? not in your example. Please [edit] to make it more representative of your needs.

Comment: Should duplicates in each individual list be merged as well?

Comment: not `list3 = [(0,123,'asd','eqw')]` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, should like this, I have edited again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `collections.defaultdict` for this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list1 = [(0,123),(1,456)]
>>> list2 = [(0,'asd'),(2,'dsa'),(0,'eqw')]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in list1+list2:
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [123, 'asd', 'eqw'], 1: [456], 2: ['dsa']})
>>> d1, d2 = dict(list1), dict(list2)
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k in d1 and k in d2]
[(0, [123, 'asd', 'eqw'])]
```